# Recommended error propogation strategy for servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I have ServiceStack service (A) which calls another ServiceStack service (B).

If (B) throws an error I can catch the WebServiceException in (A), but what is the recommended way to propogating (B)'s error back to (A)'s client? Should I rethrow (B)'s exception or just not catch it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the typed C# client for calling into (B) from (A), then yes, if you want the exception propagated to (A)'s client then you can just not catch it, and the C# client will throw any exception it encounters, which will get serialized down to (A)'s client, and if that client is using the C# ServiceClient, it will then in turn throw that exception.

The flow pretty much looks like this:

```
(A client)    ->    (A service) ->     (B client)     ->      (B service)
 deserializes            <-           deserializes    <-   throws Exception E
 and rethrows E                      and rethrows E
```

Hope that makes sense.